# Haskell add constraint to constructor

Tags: haskell, constructor, formal-languages

*Background: 

I am following a course about 'languages and automata': currently it is about regular expressions/languages, DFAs and NFAs. This question is not homework, but rather an implementation in Haskell of some things I learnt that I decided to make for myself. Only knowledge of Haskell is required to answer this question*

---

I have the following data type for a regular expression

```hs
data Regex sigma = Eps
    | Phi
    | S sigma
    | Regex sigma :. Regex sigma
    | Regex sigma :| Regex sigma
    deriving (Show,Eq,Read)
```

With this, we can define regular expressions e.g. `S 'a'`, or `S 'a' :. S 'b'`, or `Eps :| S 'a'`.
So far, so good.

Now, `Eps` (the empty string) should be the neutral element of `:.`. I.e. `Eps :. e` and `e :. Eps` should both return `e` (where `e` is any other regular expression).

So I would like to apply pattern matching to the constructor `(:.)`. Is this possible? If so, how can I implement this? If not, what is another way to achieve what I want?

I tried to define the constructor explicitly in order to apply pattern matching:

```hs
(:.) :: Regex sigma -> Regex sigma -> Regex sigma
(:.) Eps e = e
(:.) e Eps = e
(:.) e f = e :. f       --this line is obviously incorrect, but I don't know how to write it differently
```

Comment: You might be able to do this with [pattern synonyms](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html), but I’m not entirely sure. (I suspect a better approach may be to make a function `removeEps :: Regex σ -> Regex σ` which can recursively remove `Eps`s from within the `Regex` passed as argument.)

Comment: Actually, after some further reflection, I suspect you can’t do this, and furthermore it would be a bad idea anyway: if you could get this working, it would mean that you could use `(:.)` to make a `Regex σ`, but then have that same value not match the pattern `(σ :. σs)`. Furthermore, it would make some values of `Regex σ` impossible to construct, which might not be what you want.

Comment: I think I will just overload Eq then ... keeping the ‘unoptimised’ REs, but making eg Eps:.S’a’ and S’a’ equal

Comment: I suspect redefining `Eq` would also be a bad idea… with your proposed definition, it would mean you could have a situation where `r == s` but `f r /= f s`. (From the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq): ‘`==` is customarily expected to implement an equivalence relationship where two values comparing equal are indistinguishable by "public" functions’.)

Comment: Is there any way that it would work then (without violating the FP unwritten rules )

Comment: I’m not entirely sure, sorry… it might help to know what exactly you’re trying to achieve with all this.

Comment: I try to automatically create a DFA from a regular expression. This requires many computations of the Brzozowski derivative (produces a new regexp) and the subsequent comparison of the results. Every different regexp corresponds to a different state, so by taking the regexp that are ‘similar’ together, we can reduce the number of different states and hence the size of the DFA.

Comment: Ah, OK. In that case, why don’t you just define a simplification function `removeEps :: Regex σ -> Regex σ` as I suggested above, then apply that on every iteration? (Also, you might want to look at `recursion-schemes`, particularly prepromorphisms, though that could be too advanced for you depending on how much Haskell experience you have.)

Comment: Yeah I’ll do that and work with a simplification function. I’ve been looking for an explanation of prepromorphisms but all i find is memes :))

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you might want to use [*smart constructors*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors).  The basic idea is that the actual constructors of your data type are hidden, and you have special versions of those constructors that you make public.  This works great on construction, but as @bradrn hinted at in the comments, it can be confusing for users who might be deconstructing your data type.

In practice, using smart constructors would go something like this:

```hs
module Regex (Regex, eps, phi, s, (.:), (.|)) where

data Regex sigma = Eps
    | Phi
    | S sigma
    | Regex sigma :. Regex sigma
    | Regex sigma :| Regex sigma
    deriving (Show,Eq,Read)

eps :: Regex sigma
eps = Eps

s :: sigma -> Regex sigma
s = S

...

(.:) :: Regex sigma -> Regex sigma -> Regex sigma
(.:) Eps e = e
(.:) e Eps = e
(.:) e f = e :. f
```

First, notice that the actual constructors of `Regex` are not being exported.  Also notice that if one creates a `Regex` with the smart constructors, then the simplification you're looking for on `:.` happens automatically.  You can add as many simplifications in these smart constructors as you like.  Lastly, notice that `Eps .: e == e .: Eps` just like you wanted without you having to redefine the `Eq Regex` instance.

Of course, the downside of this is that users don't have access to the actual `Regex` constructors, which means that users can't deconstruct a `Regex`.  There are ways around this, such as using uni- or bi-directional patterns, but this can be confusing.  For instance (as @bradrn pointed out in comments), the value `Eps .: e` won't match the pattern `x :. y`.

There's also the issue that your derived `Read` instance could still be used to create `Regex` values that have something like `Eps :. e` in them.  One neat tip here is that now that you have smart constructors, it becomes very easy to define `simplifyRegex :: Regex σ -> Regex σ`:

```hs
simplifyRegex :: Regex sigma -> Regex sigma
simplifyRegex Eps = eps
simplifyRegex Phi = phi
simplifyRegex (S x) = s x
simplifyRegex (x :. y) = simplifyRegex x .: simplifyRegex y
simplifyRegex (x :| y) = simplifyRegex x |: simplifyRegex y
```

With this, it's easy to make a new version of `read`:

```hs
readRegex :: Read sigma => String -> Regex sigma
readRegex = simplifyRegex . read
```

---

One final interesting note: the definition of `simplifyRegex` follows a standard form that looks a lot like a fold.  In fact, we can even abstract it a bit and turn it into something that is, in essence, a fold:

```hs
foldRegex :: a -> a -> (sigma -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Regex sigma -> a
foldRegex eps phi s (.:) (|:) = go
  where
    go Eps = eps
    go Phi = phi
    go (S x) = s x
    go (x :. y) = go x .: go y
    go (x :| y) = go x |: go y
```

This function takes as arguments the thing to do for each possible `Regex` constructor and then recursively deconstructs the `Regex`, applying the thing at each point.  We can easily recover the `simplifyRegex` function by defining it as

```hs
simplifyRegex :: Regex sigma -> Regex sigma
simplifyRegex = foldRegex eps phi s (.:) (|:)
```

where we call `foldRegex` with all the smart constructors.

By releasing this function to your users, you let them deconstruct any `Regex` without actually giving them direct access to the `Regex` constructors.

To learn more about this, search for "catamorphisms" and "recursion schemes".